# Angular2 boolean model capture value with radio

Tags: angular

I have a model that takes boolean value `rational_thinker: boolean;` and a method hat sets it's value:

```
getRationalThinker(value){
    console.log(value)
    this.rational_thinker=value;
    console.log(this.rational_thinker)
}
```

How can I have two radio buttons that send true and false so that I can set the value of rational_thinker accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried binding your function to the click event?

```
<input type="radio" (click)="getRationalThinker(true)">...
```

or this (I might have the syntax a bit off)

```
<input #btn1 type="radio" value="true" (click)="getRationalThinker(btn1.value)">
```

Comment: In guess I have to bind it to themodel, otherwise in this case I am able to click both radio buttons i.e. true false

Comment: I added [(ngModel)]="rational_thinker" and it works. Thanks!